# Installing ubuntu on SD card

Tags: system-installation

I have performed an installation of Ubuntu 19.04 on a 128 GB SD card.

After going into the boot options, I can choose my SD card to boot from it but it doesn't take me to Ubuntu desktop rather a GNU GRUB version 2.02 comes up.

`ls` gives the following output:

```
(Proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gp54) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

Comment: And how was the sd card partitioned?

Comment: / - ext4 - 30 gb,
/boot - ext4 - 512 mb
/home - ext4 - rest

Comment: And is this your only drive or are there any other drives on your PC? Have you tried switching boot device using BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: I do have another ssd with windows installed on it. I did go to boot options and selected the one with ubuntu on it after which the GNU grub command line comes up.

Comment: Could it be possible that my laptop just doesn't support booting from a sd card? :(

Comment: @Ayush Goel How old is your PC? I recall my computers more than about eight years old would not boot from SD card.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron no its just 1-2 years old. HP Envy ah0044tx